# How scraping metabase with zombie

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, metabase

I would like to scrap my website who's using metabase. For that I'm using [Zombie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zombie#tabs) module.
For the example I used this url `https://stats.metabase.com/auth/login?redirect=%2F` but my website is similar.

My code :

```
const browser = new Browser({ debug: true });

browser.visit('https://stats.metabase.com/auth/login?redirect=%2F', async (result) => {
    console.log(result);

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(browser.html());
            console.log(myLog);
            resolve();
        }, 10000);
    });
});
```

Result :

> Error: Errors detected in definition of Lexer:
>   Token class: ->NullaryAggregation<- missing static 'PATTERN' property-----------------------
>   Token class: ->UnaryAggregation<- missing static 'PATTERN' property
>       at new t (http s://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/vendor.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:126:134814)
>       at Object. (ht tps://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/app-main.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:5:1161826)
>       at i (ht tps://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/vendor.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:1:410)
>       at Object. (http s://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/app-main.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:5:788893)
>       at i (htt ps://stats.metabase.co m/app/dist/vendor.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:1:410)
>       at Object. (https://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/app-main.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:5:654692)
>       at i (htt ps://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/vendor.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:1:410)
>       at Object. (h ttps://stats.metabase.co m/app/dist/app-main.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:5:1135139)
>       at i (htt ps://stats.metabase.co m/app/dist/vendor.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:1:410)
>       at Object. (htt ps://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/app-main.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db:5:1134219)
>       in htt ps://stats.metabase.c om/auth/login?redirect=%2F
>     filename: 'http s://stats.metabase.c om/app/dist/app-main.bundle.js?52d110c7445f6d30f2db' }

Expected:

> No error

After a lot try: changed the userAgent, set a timeout, slowed down the loading of the page. Nothing work... Someone have an idea ?